# Who kills the Omega in the final timeline?

Tags: edge-of-tomorrow, all-you-need-is-kill

In the penultimate timeline "loop" that we see in Edge Of Tomorrow,

> Cage drops the bundle of grenades into the Omega, which dies, and its "blood" is absorbed back into Cage as he dies - giving him back the power he lost earlier on.

However, as we see in the final sequence,

> this destruction has *already happened* when he awakes back in the helicopter - as seen in the TV broadcast from the General. It's also evident that Rita didn't succeed in this task on her own, as she's back in the training room where he first meets her.

So who killed it/how did it die?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vY_Ry8J_jdw

Comment: I expect this is likely the best answer :P I added the tag for the book, though I haven't read it yet. Hopefully there's an answer in there, if I didn't miss something from the movie.

Comment: @AdamS The book is much different from the movie. In the book there is no distinction between "alphas" and "omegas", and the finale of the book in particular is very different.

Comment: @calccrypto - Youtube deleted it :(

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Cage did, enabled by the unique physiology of the Omega.

To elaborate, the film explained that the Omega was the thing that rebooted the time loop.  The death of an Alpha was the trigger, but the actual mechanism was the Omega.

Somehow, by killing the Omega, and then dying himself (with the Omega blood mingled into his own), Cage started a new time loop.  Something about the Omega's ability to manipulate time meant that when this new time loop started, the Omega's destruction was carried over.  I'd argue this is due to the Omega not just remembering past time loops but somehow physically going back in time itself when a time loop restarts.  Its destruction therefore brought its dead form back in time with the new time loop.  From the standpoint of all the humans, this meant there was a living Omega that suddenly was replaced with a dead Omega, and this triggered some large energy release, as reported in the news at the end of the film.

Since the film takes a perspective of the humans, we have limited information on the aliens and their capabilities.  We only know what the humans know, so we don't know for certain what happens normally when an Omega is destroyed.

Comment: That is an excellent answer that I had not considered.

Comment: Well, if the Omega "physically [went] back in time itself when a time loop restarts", wouldn't that be how Cage's power works too ? Why then wouldn't he be dead each time he wakes up ? There is some contradiction here. Unfortunately, I don't have a suggestion so I just leave a comment.

Comment: It was my understanding that Cage doesn't control the time loop power at all. The Omega restarts the loop to prevent the Alpha from actually dying. When Cage gets the blood on him and "steals" the power, the Omega redoes the loop to prevent him from staying dead (presumably involuntarily as the Mimics know he's stolen the power).

Comment: I feel that you understand the time-looping mechanism much better than the actual writers.

Comment: Another possibility: Highlander style time travel rules, aka "There can only be one."  Cage absorbs the Omega's blood, thus becoming the Omega, resets time on death, now there's two Omegas, and Cage-Omega takes precedence causing Original-Omega to go boom.